# Is there possible to have only two values in Slider Extender (Ajax Control Toolkit ).

Tags: asp.net, ajax, slider, ajaxcontroltoolkit

Is there any way to have have only two values for the Slider Extender. The Slider should go from minimum to maximum and nothing between.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="ZeroOrOneTextBox"></asp:TextBox>
<act:SliderExtender runat="server"  ID="ZeroOrOneSlider"
  Minimum="0" Maximum="1" Steps="2"
  BoundControlID="ZeroOrOneLabel" TargetControlID="ZeroOrOneTextBox"></act:SliderExtender>    
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="ZeroOrOneLabel"></asp:Label>
```